# Optimal solution algorithm for K-center problems

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm wondering if there is an algorithm that calculates the optimal solution of a typical k-center problem (more than one dimension). I've tried, but without success, to find this algorithm. Does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: Sure, iterate over each subset of $ k $ vertices, return the one with the smallest maximum distance to the subset. If you want an efficient algorithm, the problem is NP-hard in 2 or more dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

An optimal solution for the k-center problem can be found by an exhaustive search over the solution space, and by picking the best solution. The problem is NP-Hard for more than 2 dimensions, and moreover any $\delta$-approximation for $\delta < 2$ is NP-hard.